# How to get the total minutes from 2 fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the total minutes in the result, sample

field 1 14:30
field 2 14:45
result 00:15

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/oxq5u1hw/)

I'm using the following code, however, I only want to get 24 hours.
14:46:22 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) NO GOOD
14:46:22 I WANT THIS RESULT and also the total in hte

```js
$(
  function() {
    let lastFocusEl = null;

    $('#time').click(function() {
      var time = new Date();
      if (lastFocusEl) lastFocusEl.value = time.toTimeString();
    });

    let f = function() {
      lastFocusEl = this
    };
    $('#time-holder').focus(f);
    $('#time-holder2').focus(f);

  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="" id="time-holder">
<input type="text" value="" id="time-holder2">
<input type="text" value="" id="result">

<input type="button" value="time" name="timer" id="time">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pull off just the parts you want from the Date for the input values.

```js
$(()=>{
  let lastFocusEl = null;
  
  $('#time').on('click', e => {
    if (!lastFocusEl) return;

    let time = new Date();
      
    // pull off just the parts you want into the value
    lastFocusEl.value = `${time.getHours()}:${time.getMinutes()}:${time.getSeconds()}`;
  });
  
  $('#time-holder, #time-holder2').on('focus', e => lastFocusEl = e.target);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="" id="time-holder">
<input type="text" value="" id="time-holder2">
<input type="text" value="" id="result">

<input type="button" value="time" name="timer" id="time">
```

Comment: great, how can i get the total of minutes in the 3rd field?

Comment: @privacymx before I update the answer to include that, how would you attempt to go about that?